# Finding special feature in a solution of a differential equation $y'' = x^{2}y$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, differential

Given a differential equation $y'' = x^{2}y$ and its solution with $y(0)=1$ and $y'(0)=0$, how can I prove that this $y$ is an even function and has $y(x)>0$ for all x?

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: To show the solution is even: If you change variables $x$ to $-x$, the DE (and the initial conditions) are unchanged.

Comment: Okay I got it, thank you very much!

Comment: Alright I get that solved. Prove that $y(x)$ is even as mentioned above, and write $y'(x)=\int_{0}^{x} s^{2}y(s)ds$ to prove that when $x>0$, $y(x)>0$.